# api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll missing when using Win 10 SDK

Tags: windows, redistributable

I'm currently using MSVC 2017, which comes with Win 10 API. I need to use dynamic C++ libs linking, so I install the MSVC 2017 redistributables in the installer. But now I tested it in Windows 7 and 8 and I get this on both:

```
This program can't start because api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is missing. Try to reinstall this.
```

Then there's this:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows

But I can hardly force customers to search through MS hotfixes and install some obviously. So what exactly am I supposed to do to make things a bit more seemless?

Comment: Nothing to do with "hotfixes", the UCRT is distributed through Windows Update.  That you did not keep these test machine updated is not relevant to what your customers will do.  Any customer that intentionally does not use Windows Update is always going to be a big support headache and you can't force an update on them when they explicitly opted out of getting any.

Comment: Ok thanks for the info. Unfortunately my customers are often a bit, ehm, crazy, keeping computers not connected and stuff... I'll try Win 8.1 SDK then.

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with the SDK target either.  VS2013 is the last VS version that builds programs that don't depend on the UCRT.

Comment: Hmmm, so either people will have updated windows, or I have to link statically? That's quite a problem... I need to link dynamically, so now I have no clue what to do...

Comment: According to this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows
:Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 creates a dependency on the Universal CRT when applications are built by using the Windows 10 Software Development Kit ...: